# SQL Azure Firewall Rules on New Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We've been using SQL Azure for about a year now. In order to directly access the server outside of Azure you need to add a firewall rule in SQL Azure. That's good.

The old portal [had a way to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/09/09/what-s-new-in-sql-azure-management-portal-part-ii-of-ii.aspx) and it was easy enough even if it was icky Silverlight.

However, as far as I can tell, the old Silverlight portal is retired. And the new portal does NOT have a way to manage firewall rules. Am I missing something?

Microsoft still says you can access the "current portal" here, but clicking it takes you to the new one: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/portals/

Answer (score 7):

In the new portal, click on:

1. SQL Databases
2. In the datagrid under the SERVER column, click your server name.
3. Click the Configure tab on the top.

Comment: BTW, the silverlight portal hasn't been retired just yet. When in the preview portal, hover over the "Preview" box at the top of the page and click on "take me to the previous portal".

Comment: Agreed it is hard to find, and a bit of a potential security issue as it prompts you to add new IP addresses every time it changes but not to manage old ones.

Comment: A don't see anything at this place which allow to add ip to the firewall

Comment: I don't see a firewall icon at all but 'opening in visual studio' give you the option. Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

On new Azure Portal you can :

1. "All resources"
2. Search your database by name
3. Select your database
4. "Tools"
5. "Open In Visual Studio"
6. "Configure your firewall"
7. "Add client IP"

[image: Steps to add new IP address into firewall in new Azure Portal]

Comment: WTF!!!! There is no firewall icon anywhere to be found but if I click open in VS it gives me this option? since when is VS a tool for configuring infrastructure, and why don't I have a firewall icon ?

Comment: Finally they added a new button ... ¬¬

Answer (score 1):

Now is available a new button :

[image: Set firewall rules]